# I need to access adapter of listview from a background thread

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-adapter, android-context

I am working on a Chat app, and as the title says, I want to access `adapter` of `ListView` from a background thread to add new elements (messages) to it without creating new `ListView` and adapter instances because that leads to refresh the `ListView` and scroll up again while the user is watching the last message at bottom, and if I try to set my adapter as `static` from my chat activity it tells me that it may cause memory leaks because Adapter is using a context.

1- Is there a way to update the `ListView` adapter by creating a new instance of it from my background thread without scrolling back to first when updated or deleting my previous message of the `ListView`?

2- if not, then if I try to use `getApplicationContext()` in the adapter so that it would not cause leaks would it work fine? because from this topic I read that application context does not inflate layouts
https://www.aurigait.com/blog/Best+practices-of-appropriate-Context-in-Android/

Comment: Why dont you switch back to the main thread? For example with [View.post(Runnable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: I actually do that becuase i have to in order to access the UI elements and put the Chat.adapter.add() call inside it but as you see the adapter is static.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use RecyclerView with ListAdapter?

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea which is using a static adapter and remove it's reference from my chat activity when it is destroyed so that it won't cause leaks.